# hide "Switch to desktop version"

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have created a website using Joomla 2.5. When I open the website on mobile, I see option at the bottom as **Switch to desktop version**. How can I hide this notification?

I don't want to use this option as I don't want user to switch to Desktop version on mobile.

[This is link](http://smart-kw.com/testingSite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, are you sing a template? It can be done via changing the PHP or via CSS. Usually in the template folder you would find a mobile.php or something like this. There in the bottom you should find this feature just comment it. Let me know what framework you using to specify a little more.

CSS Solution:

```
#m-desktop {display:none;}
```

Comment: I have not tried. Once I try, I will let you know. BUT I feel it will work... CSS will do the trick...

Answer (score 0):

Lots of users on tablets prefer desktop to mobile so I would think twice. Still to find the file find the language key in the template language file then g r e p for it. Then comment it out.